# React Router match path from query string fallback

Tags: reactjs, nginx, url, react-router, html5-history

I want to be able to serve a React app using React Router both on an Apache and NGINX server **without having to change any default Apache/NGINX configs**.
The problem is that the application will only be served when you access the root folder, as any sub path leads to a 404 (app.com/ works but not app.com/settings).

For the **Apache** server, I include a `.htaccess` file that automatically loads index.html if the requested resource is not found.
For **NGINX** as far as I understand there is no way to properly load the application in a sub-path unless you change the config file.

My solution for this would be to add the option in the app to store the Router path as a query string, instead of in `location.pathname`, something like **app.com/?page=settings** instead of **app.com/settings**.

Is there any way to add some sort of a middleware in the React router such that when accessing **app.com/?page=settings** the Router path will be set to **/settings**. Also, when the user navigates and the router should update the URL in the address bar, it should change it to **app.com/?page=user/dashboard** instead of **app.com/user/dashboard**.

I am looking for any solution that would allow the Router to work both with a path and with the path specified as a query string variable.

If needed, here is how my router looks:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path={BaseRoutes.Home} exact>
                <Redirect to={BaseRoutes.Domains} />
            </Route>

            <Route path={[BaseRoutes.Stats, BaseRoutes.Settings, '/*']} component={SidebarMain} />

            <div className={`content-area ${classes.content}`}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={BaseRoutes.Stats} component={Stats} />
                    <Route exact path={BaseRoutes.Home} component={Domains} />
                    <Route exact path={BaseRoutes.Settings} component={Settings} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
</Router>;
```

Comment: The reason for this is that I want non-technical people to be able to use the application without changing any configs, but at the same time keep the URL pretty (without query strings) when possible (when the server can load the index.html file even when the URL accessed contains a path).

Comment: I also use the useLocation() and browserHistory.location.pathname in multiple places in my app, so I would prefer those values to be populated too from the query string path variable.

Comment: well the way you should do it is specify the path with the query and route to the correct component. i believe you are overcomplicating this. the query is for sending data. but if you want you could have one route and in that route redirect to different components using UseLocation from reactrouter based on the query path. but this is not how websites should operate

Comment: @Grantmitchell You are right, I was overcomplicating. I can just toggle betwen Router and HashRouter I think.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized I can just use `HashRouter` instead of `Router` for NGINX...

So, depending on whether the user's setting of having "pretty" URLs or hash based URLs I can either load the BrowserHistory Router or the HashRouter:

`<Router history={browserHistory}>` OR `<HashRouter>`

To switch between them I did:

```
let SupportedRouter: React.ElementType = HashRouter;
if (MY_CONDITION) {
    SupportedRouter = Router;
}

// Render
<SupportedRouter history={browserHistory}>
</SupportedRouter>
```

I had to cast them to `React.ElementType`, otherwise optionally passing history lead to TypeScript errors: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631#issuecomment-472606019